# PHP - Bot Telegram sends message to Channel and Reply in the Chat

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

My PHP Script - which has a Github library (link at the end), is communicating with a Telegram Bot, but this Bot sends messages to both the Channel and the Channel Chat.

```
$canalID= "@xxx";
$botKey     = "xx:xxxx-yyy";

$requestFactory = new Http\Factory\Guzzle\RequestFactory();
$streamFactory  = new Http\Factory\Guzzle\StreamFactory();
$client         = new Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client();

$apiClient = new \TgBotApi\BotApiBase\ApiClient($requestFactory, $streamFactory, $client);
$bot       = new \TgBotApi\BotApiBase\BotApi($botKey, $apiClient, new \TgBotApi\BotApiBase\BotApiNormalizer());

$text = "Olá";

$arr = ["parseMode" => "HTML"];

$bot->send(\TgBotApi\BotApiBase\Method\SendMessageMethod::create($canalID, $text, $arr));
```

I would like the robot to just send messages to the Channel, and stop replicating itself in the Chat of that Channel.

He does not belong to the Chat, only to the Channel.

I don't understand why he replies the message ..

https://github.com/tg-bot-api/bot-api-base

Comment: So you don't want any reply from the channel?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I want him to send the message to the Channel, as he is doing .. The problem is that he is also sending it to the Channel Chat, that is, he sends a duplicate and there are always two notifications (one on the Channel, one on the Chat of the Channel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function (**no library needed**):

```
<?php

tg("Olá");

function tg($text) {
$data = ['chat_id' => '@xxx', 'disable_web_page_preview' => true, 'parse_mode' => 'HTML', 'text' => $text];
file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/xx:xxxx-yyy/sendMessage?'.http_build_query($data));
}
```

**Replace:**

- @xxx (chat_id);
- xx:xxxx-yyy (botKey).

Comment: correct url is: https://api.telegram.org/bot<xx:xxxx-yyy>